# What should I consider regarding recessed lighting above kitchen sink?

Tags: lighting, recessed-lighting, kitchens

I'm planning to replace the million year old florescent light (I think it was the first one ever made) above my kitchen sink with a couple recessed lights.  Is there anything specific I should be thinking about when selecting the type of fixture / bulbs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've got insulation in the ceiling, you'll need to get **IC** (insulation contact) rated fixtures -- they're also known as closed-can.  I have a small soffet built over my sink; if yours is similar, make sure that the fixture you select will fit.  Other than that, don't exceed the wattage for the fixture and you'll be OK.

**EDIT:** On second thoughts, use an IC rated fixture regardless of whether or not you have insulation.  Over a sink, you're likely to have a lot of steam and if it's an open-can fixture, the [stack effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_effect) is going to draw much of it up into the space over the ceiling.

Comment: Good point about the IC fixture.

Comment: What about the lights themselves incandescent, compact florescence, LED, something different?

Comment: Use a flood that fills the opening.  It can be whatever type you like (maybe not halogens though).  Wattage ratings are for incandescents, so a CFL or LED is going to be OK.  I use a daylight CFL flood.